# best way to refer to war files using gradle cargo plugin

Tags: maven, repository, gradle, cargo

I'm working on a gradle build which builds several war files and publishes them to the local maven repo. In another project I want gradle to deploy all the new war files to a tomcat server and then run webetsts against them. 
 I have it working but the only way I was able to refer to the war files using cargo was with something like :

```
deployable {
    file = file( 'file://' + new File(System.getProperty('user.home'), '.m2/repository/company/project/5.0.0/myWar-5.0.0.war').absolutePath)
    context = 'myContext'        
}
```

I'm going to make another pass through this and make the version numbers dynamic etc. But my question is : "Is this the best way to do something like this?" It seems odd to construct a file path to my local maven repo. I would think that since I added the war files as dependencies that the cargo plugin would just know about them but it doesn't seem to work that way.

Comment: Already answered over at http://forums.gradle.org. Please don't double-post.

Comment: the direct link to the post is http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/can_the_cargo_plugin_deploy_war_files_from_the_local_maven_repository